# Vision Transformer ViT Parameter count

Tags: deep-learning, computer-vision, transformer, attention-mechanism

The Vision Transformer paper *An Image is with 16x16 words* by Dosovitskiy et al. (2021)
includes the following table:
[image]

Can someone explain how they get the parameter counts or where my calculation is wrong?
Let's look at ViT-Base: Each attention layer requires three $768 \times 768$ matrixes to produces $Q, K, V$ from the input. Then the result of each attention layer is concatenated and transformed back to $D$ requiring another $(12 \cdot 768) \times 768$ matrix.

With 12 heads this adds up to $12 \cdot 768 \cdot 768 + 12 \cdot 768 \cdot 768 \approx 14M$ parameter per MSA head. And we add the parameters for the MLP ($2 * 768*3072 \approx 4.7M$).

Using 12 layers this would imply $12 \cdot (14 + 4.7) \approx 224M$ parameter instead of the 86M specified?

Answer (score 1):

My calculation was based on a wrong understanding of the self attention mechanism. In *Attention is all you need* the authors point out that they won't use the full $768 \times 768$ matrices when they make use of multi-head attention but rather use $768 / h$ as the internal dimension where $h$ is the number of heads.